# How to make local testing environment for app in docker

Tags: networking, python, docker, container, odoo

I am trying to run an odoo application at work on our local network so that workers can start testing the modules we built. I am able to run and get the addons to run on the host computer but cannot get it to run on the network, every time I try to access the IP address on another machine connected to the same LAN it cannot access it. It is a Ubuntu machine running docker and I am using the bridge network trying to expose the ip address to the network. How can I run a docker container on a local network and have other computers on the same LAN access it? If anyone can give me any advice it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!